# Stop weather forecast calendar events on smart watch

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, android-wear, weather

I have a Garmin Fenix 5 connected to a Pixel XL.
On the Fenix 5, the calendar widget shows a weather forecast as an all day event. This is redundant (there is already a weather widget on the Garmin), and unwelcome (it clutters the calendar view and makes it less useful).  These Forecast "events" do not show up in the calendar app on my phone.  Where are they coming from and how can I remove them?

*Context and what I have tried*:

I have two cloud accounts in android account manager with calendars: google account (personal) and office365/exchange account (work).  I have tried hiding all calendars from the calendar app settings (including the "Holidays" and "Birthdays" under "Other" and "Events from Gmail"), the result was that *no* events are shown on the phone, and *only* the mysterious forecast events are seen on the watch.  I have gone to each calendar on both google and office 365 via the web, there is no forecast events shown.  I have explored for relevant settings for both via the web sites, and outlook for mac (for o365).  In office365, there is an option to show a weather forecast event, but I have turned it off for all calendars, with no result.  I also uninstalled the google "news and weather" app and do not have any other weather app installed except google assistant.

One last data point: the forcast is for a location I lived previously, before I even got my Garmin.

How can a calendar event to show on the smart watch but not the calendar app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an answer per-say, I was able to see the calendar where the events where coming from by downloading the app Any.do and connecting to google calendar, even though it still did not show on Google Calendar app nor web.

After removing the google account totally from my phone (Android Settings->Accounts), and then re-adding it, this weather calendar did not reappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you stumble upon the same issue - here's a solution, that worked perfectly 4me:

https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/6260804?msgid=22824877

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Consider [edit]ing to summarize the content and/or expand the answer!